# How to display a php variable into html

Tags: php, html

I just want to know how can I display a javascript variable into html?

Below is my php code:

```
var duration = <? echo $postduration; ?>;
```

(The variable above uses php to retrieve a php variable)

Thank you

Comment: What you've written above is NOT JavaScript retrieving a variable. PHP is outputting the value of $postduration into the text that will be later run by the browser as JavaScript.. If you don't understand the order of things you're in for a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: There's something not smelling very good in `uses javascript to retrieve a php variable`. Do you want that the javascript read a value that is stored on the server? If this is the case what you need is AJAX.

Comment: Well what I meant was I want to use the above code "var duration = <? echo $postduration; ?>;" to get the value from $postduration (which is 100) and then use html to display it by retrieving the javascript variable

Comment: @user1131869 PS this site is not a debugging help desk. Please consider re-posting your entire php file into a new, well-formulated question that doesn't assume anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Make your code more concise with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):**

(1) Add this in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

(2) Create an element where you want the variable to be displayed, and give it an ID, e.g.:

```
<span id="printHere"></span>
```

(3) Add this in your JavaScript:

```
var duration="<?php echo $postduration ?>";
$('#printHere').html(duration);
```

**For your PHP, try the following two options:**

```
<?=$postduration?>
```

or...

```
<?php echo $postduration; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am actually jquery code already but it does not display the text. I have the relevant script tag but it is not displaying anything in my span. I will display my code in a Jsfiddle so you can see it. http://jsfiddle.net/SLbKX/4/, Do I need to display the php variable in php tags above the jquery or can it go below the jquery because at the moment the php variable is below the jquery code

Comment: It should go above so that you are referencing a variable that exists already.. Assuming you have it laid out the way it looks in your jsfiddle, it should work if PHP is generating the page. You are editing a .php file, right?

Comment: Yes it is a php file, it is still not displaying it suprisingly, my code is in this updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SLbKX/7/, I can't see anything wrong but I don't know why it is not working

Comment: @user1131869 when you hit CTRL+U in the browser you should see the value written there in the JavaScript. See my update on PHP syntax.

Comment: Still not displaying it in the span, all spellings are correct, cannot see a mistake, tried both your php syntax's but still doesn't display anything

Comment: How are you posting `durationChosen` to the page? Try removing `$postduration = $_POST['durationChosen'];` and just manually setting `$postduration = "testValue"` for test purposes.

Comment: I tried the "testValue" but it didn't output anything. I am displaying the $postduration = $_POST['durationChosen']; inbetween the php tags like shown in the fiddle and it is displayed above the jquery in the <head> tag above the <script> tag

Comment: Is PHP running on your computer? Do you have a local server configured? Maybe try the first two bullet point of http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php.

Comment: PHP is working fine - it works if I echo the php in html. But what I want is to be able to use jquery to retrieve the php variable so that I can perform calculations on it. The answer to the calculation belongs to the php variable and this can change at any time. If I display it in html using php can I still use jquery to perform calculations on it and would this mean page loading would occur if answer keeps changing ( I don't want page loads)?

Comment: You may have some misunderstandings about the technologies involved.. I'd be happy to chat with you once you get to 20 rep.

Comment: Ok no probs this is my last comment then I will figure it out, I just want to ask you are you sure the jquery code and html code you provided to me is correct, because I have a php variable in my jquery involved in an if statement which worked but if I try and use it in the query code you provided me then that didn't display anything.

Comment: Tried it, still didn't work, I will try and figure it out, thanks for you help anyway :)

Comment: Realised why it didn't work, I had to move var duration="<?php echo $postduration ?>"; outside the document ready function and put the $('#printHere').html(duration); in the document ready function

Answer (score 8):

Why don't use just display the php variable directly into the html?

Lets just say `$postduration` echos "some." Here is the javascript code to echo "some":

```
Here is <script>document.write(duration)</script> text.
```

Here will be the output:

```
Here is some text.
```

Comment: Because I want to use javascript for calculation on that variable and php requires page loads when calculation changes while javascript doesn't

Comment: [@user1131869](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1131869/user1131869) Will you do the calculation with PHP or with Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('yourElementId').innerHtml = duration;
```

Comment: This is probably the most sensible way. Maybe change from 'yourDiv' to 'yourElementID' ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to add a DIV to a page with the content of the DIV being the value of your PHP var:

```
 <script>
 var duration = <? echo $postduration; ?>;
 var div = document.createElement("DIV");
 div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(duration));
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, wait, that's wrong. First of all, the javascript above does not "retrieve" anything from anywhere (neither php, nor anyplace else). Php generates the javascript, meaning that if $postduration is 5, you will get `var duration = 5;`, and if postduration = "test", you will get `var duration = test;` (which is invalid javascript and **will** crash/cause unwanted things to happen in your application.

Last, to get a variable from javascript into html, you either replace the content of some other object (with `innerHTML` or something like that), or you create a new element and insert that into the page.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SLbKX/

Comment: I just want to know that can a <span> tag have 2 id's, because I want to display the content from the variable in a span but I am thinking if I can use 1 id to display the content from the variable and another id to do some calculation on that span?

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like that, use the `"{$}"` to put a variable in, and the `""` are important.

```
$_var=2;
echo "hi var is {$_var}";
```