# How to display a variable date in a Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to display a variable date in a Wordpress page.

I know you can use Javascript or PHP to display the current date in Wordpress, but how can you do it in a certain page (HTML).

Let's say I want to place this string:

```
The promotion ends on the "the_date"
```

Also, I want to modify the date to add 2 more days. So if today's date is 7th of January of 2015, the post should show 9th of January of 2015.

Comment: `The promotion ends on "<?php code goes here ?>"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a javascript variable into html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765855/how-to-display-a-javascript-variable-into-html)

Comment: Do you want 2 days from the current date "Today" or 2 days from the posted date?

Comment: Two day from Today variable @Demodave

Comment: @alexgarciab Because then the promotion would never end cause it will always be 2 days in the future.

Comment: Oh, I see you are doing a marketing gimmick of be the 1st 10 callers or call in the next 30 mins before it expires when in reality it never does.

Comment: Yep, marketing stuff @Demodave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds 2 days "today"

```
<?php echo date('j F, Y', strtotime('+2 days')); ?>
```

I'm using div tags for html but you can use any tags you want.

If you are inserting directly into wordpress post textbox you should install this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/)

and this code

```
[insert_php] echo date('j F, Y', strtotime('+2 days')); [/insert_php]
```

But keep in mind if users insert php code it would render as well. So it all depends on your use and need.

Comment: <div><?php php code coes here ?></div> just put it in php tags <?php ?> It will render wherever you put it.

Comment: It is showing the PHP code itself without interpreting it.

Comment: Is your file .html? Then you will have to alter your httpd.conf or .htaccess file to run html as php or add a .php file "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: I am working with Wordpress. I am editing text in HTML format but the page is generated dynamically with PHP.

Comment: Are you using templates is it a smarty structure?

Comment: Yes, I am using a template.

Comment: Is this public or on your local machine? Is other php code redering? Is this a new setup of Wordpress? Do you have conflicting htaccess files? Is it a smarty template? depending on how old your smarty is you could try {php}php code{/php}

Comment: Just now I am using this line of code `<?php echo date('j F, Y', strtotime('+2 days')); ?>` and nothing appears. This is a basic Wordpress installation with no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Well your code is correct, you just have something going on with rendering your php application try a basic <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Like I said check your htaccess files or your httpd.conf file to see if you are rendering your html[htm] file if it is .html as php.

Comment: The phpinfo line of code is not working neither. I think there is something wrong with the htaccess file. What would be the lines of code to make Wordpress capable of interpret PHP code in HTML files?

Comment: Where are you placing the php code? In the page or via edit textbox?

Comment: Ok, I downloaded wordpress to debug you need to install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/ if you are putting it directly into wordpress textbox post and put this code [insert_php]
echo date('j F, Y', strtotime('+2 days'));
[/insert_php] I updated answer

Comment: Awesome @Demodave - Now it is working fine. The only problem I have is that it is showing the date in English and I would like to show it in Spanish. January = Enero

Comment: Got it: `[insert_php] setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y",strtotime('+2 days')); [/insert_php]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PHP code for it. It will always be 2 days in the future though.

```
<?=date("Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"))?>
```

Comment: Should I place this code in the HTML view of the Edit page of Wordpress? It is not working there.