# display javascript variable in html code

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, variables

im really new to javascript and im kind of stuck with two problems :

-first problem: how can i display  variables in html code, here's mine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $first = 1000;
var $seconde = 50;
var $percentage = 0;
function pourcentage(somme, but) {
    percentage = ((somme / but ) * 100);} 
function incremente() {
    $first = $first + 10 ;}   
</script>
```

and here's what im trying to do:

```
 <li><a href="#">first variable $first seconde one is $seconde</a></li>
```

-2nd problem is how to use a function onclick:

`<li class="blue"><a href="#" onclick="incremente()">stuff</a></li>`

thank you for your time :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a javascript variable into html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765855/how-to-display-a-javascript-variable-into-html)

Comment: You have a long way to go...

Comment: yes the only langages i used for programming are c, pascal and some object-oriented java :/

Comment: What's the fetish with the `$` variables nowadays?

Comment: i was able to display the variables using <?php ?> inside html code    <li><a href="#">first variable <?php echo $first ?></a></li> but it seems that it cant work with the onclik= function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $first = 1000;
var $seconde = 50;
var $percentage = 0;
var place1=document.getElementById('first');
var place2=document.getElementById('second');
function pourcentage(somme, but) {
    percentage = ((somme / but ) * 100);
  alert('pourcentage = '+percentage+'%');
} 
function incremente() {
  
    $first = $first + 10 ;
  place1.innerHTML=$first;
  place2.innerHTML=$seconde;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">first variable is <span id="first"></span> and seconde one is<span id="second"></span></a>
<br><button onclick="pourcentage(100,5)">pourcentage</button>
<br><button onclick="incremente()">incremente</button>
```

Comment: it displays (first variable is and seconde one is)  doesnt show variables :/    ps:it worked perfectly on run code snippet*

Answer (score 1):

You would generally use a framework with some sort of templating to accomplish this.  However, there are many ways to inject javascript variables into your html.
Inside your javascript file or script block:

```
var $first = 1000;
var $seconde = 50;

//target the element whose html you want to edit
var el = document.getElementById('targetMe');

//use the innerHTML() method of DOM elements to edit the HTML of the targeted element
el.innerHTML = "first variable "+ $first +" second one is "+$seconde;
```

to add event to a function use `addEventListener` on a node.

```
el.addEventListener("click", pourcentage.bind(window, 100, 5), false);
```

Answer (score -2):

nice to meet you friend.

first, pure javascript is hard to display variable in html directly. If you want to do like your code, check javascript libraries(AngularJS or hadlebar)

2nd

```
<html>
...
<script>
function yourFunction() {
  //your code in here..
}

</script>

...

<li><a href="#" onclick="yourFunction()">something</a></li>
```